# UITextView - disable vertical scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextview

How can I disable vertical scrolling in my UITextView? I want it to basically just scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In some circumstances, when trying to clamp down on unwanted UITextView scrolling I have found it helpful to add something like the following to the UITextView delegate (this is a UIScrollView delegate method but, of course, UITextView inherits from UIScrollView). This might work for you.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(id)scrollView
{
      CGPoint origin = [scrollView contentOffset]; 
      [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(origin.x, 0.0)];
}
```

What about the scrollEnabled property? Setting the scrollEnabled property to NO stops the user from scrolling (in both directions), but there are occasions where the system sends `setContentOffset:animated:` messages to a UITextView. The scrollEnabled property applies to both vertical and horizontal scrolling. Given your question, you might want to leave scrollEnabled as is.

Comment: This answer also allowed me to prevent sideways scrolling by locking down the x axis instead of y.

Answer (score 5):

You can change it from Xcode -

[image: Click here]

Answer (score 4):

Solution for disabling vertical scrolling for **Swift 4**:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let origin: CGPoint = scrollView.contentOffset
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: origin.x, y: 0.0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your custom textView subclass, you can override -gestureRecognizerShouldBegin to disable the scroll.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        if (gestureRecognizer.view == self)
        {
            return NO;
        }
        else
        {
            return [super gestureRecognizerShouldBegin: gestureRecognizer];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just use a UITextField if you dont want vertical scrolling?

Comment: because you can't swipe left and right nicely in a uitextfield. you can't scroll in a uitextfield

Comment: Its not possible to disable vertical scrolling while keeping horizontal scrolling in a default UITextView.  YOu will have to subclass it and roll your own

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `contentSize` to the height of the view.

You'll use this:

```
CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(widthOfContent, heightOfView);
[myScrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];
```

Answer (score -1):

place your UITextView in a UIScrollView.
Set your UITextView.frame to a Size the complete Text fits in a Line and set the contenSize of the ScrollView to the size of your UITextView.frame.

Cheers
nettz