# How to disable vertical scrolling in UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uitextview

I just want to disable the vertical scrolling in my UITextView **while keeping the horizontal scrolling**.

I found some similar questions here, however, none of them seemed to work for me. What I have tried is:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let origin: CGPoint = scrollView.contentOffset
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: origin.x, y: 0.0)
}

func makeTextView() {
    textView = UITextView()
    textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height:50)
    scrollView.addSubview(textView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    scrollViewDidScroll(textView)
}
```

Even after trying this though, the UITextView still scrollable in the vertical direction.

[image: Here's an image of what my app and layout looks like, I hope it helps a little]

Comment: Did you tried setting the scrollEnabled option to false directly from Attributes inspector?

Comment: I haven't since I thought that would disable both horizontal and vertical scrolling and I want to keep the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I doubt you can achieve this behavior using UITextView.

Why you just not try adding UIScrollView + UILabel?

Comment: @Ken I am confused on how you are setting up your views. The line `scrollView.addSubview(textView)` suggest that you are adding your text view to a scroll view. What exactly is your view hierarchy and setup? Can you give us enough information to try are reproduce your issue? It might be that your scroll view is working correctly (without vertical scrolling) but your text view can still vertically scroll without it. Also I assume the delegates are correctly connected...

Answer (score 1):

UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you can prevent the view from scrolling by setting the property isScrollEnabled to false.

`textView.isScrollEnabled = false`

Comment: Is there a way to only disable the vertical scrolling and keep the horizontal scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to disable scrolling of textview:

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

And add your textView inside `UIScrollView`. It will give you the result what you expected.

[image: Horizontal Scroll View]

---

Or You can do programmatically as follows:

```
    var textView = UITextView()
    var scrollView = UIScrollView()
    func makeTextView() {
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .green
        textView.backgroundColor = .red

        textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda."
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        scrollView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height:50)
        textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height:50)

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(textView)

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
```

Comment: Wont this also disable horizontal scrolling? I want to keep the horizontal scrolling and only disable the vertical scrolling.

Comment: Yes, it will disable both of the scrolling, You didn't mention to keep horizontal scrolling in question. :)

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit it, is there a way to disable only the vertical?

Comment: So I make a new UIScrollView every time I make a new UITextView? Sorry, I'm kinda new to swift.

Comment: @Ken, Yes you are right. OR you can make custom class of UIScrollView by doing SubClass of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195663/discussion-between-bhavik-modi-and-ken).

Answer (score 1):

There are two main solutions:

1. In your View controller, if you linked your textview to an outlet

   ```
   textView.isScrollEnabled = false
   ```
2. In the storyboard (if you are not coding the UI)

   You can set the scrollEnabled option from true to false in the Attributes inspector on the right side of your screen if you clicked on the UITextView

Answer (score 0):

for vertical scrolling `swift 4` :

```
    let origin: CGPoint = scrollView.contentOffset
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: origin.x, y: 0.0)
}
```

or you can change it like this :

`textView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false`

Comment: I have tried this, in my code above, but for some reason it doesn't disable the vertical scrolling.

Comment: Take a look at this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155052/uitextview-disable-vertical-scrolling

Comment: Thanks, I read over the answer, but I think it's similar to what I did above, which doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: could you try changing ```scrollView.addSubview(textView)``` with ```scrollViewDidScroll(textView)``` ?
I mean after doing all settings then you can add it to subview !

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but you also need to set the textView delegate on `makeTextView()` like so:

```swift
textView.delegate = self
```

Also, don't forget to implement the `UITextViewDelegate` on your viewcontroller. Like this:

`class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView, So you can set textView `contentSize` like so:

```
textView.contentSize = CGSize(width: , height: )
```

With this, if you don't want horizontal scrolling you can set textView width and it's `contentSize` width equal and vise versa for vertical scrolling.

You can use it as per your need to restrict one of the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

An example of this can be made by placing your text view inside a scroll view. A working example of this would be the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    private var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView = {
            let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 150.0, width: 300.0, height: 100.0))
            scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            view.addSubview(scrollView)
            return scrollView
        }()

        textView = {
            let textView = UITextView(frame: .zero)
            scrollView?.addSubview(textView)
            textView.text = "Some fairly long text to be able to debug multiline and size being out of bounds of this item\nSome fairly long text to be able to debug multiline and size being out of bounds of this item\nSome fairly long text to be able to debug multiline and size being out of bounds of this item"
            textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
            textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            textView.sizeToFit()
            textView.isScrollEnabled = false
            return textView
        }()

        scrollView.contentSize = textView.bounds.size
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let origin: CGPoint = scrollView.contentOffset
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: origin.x, y: 0.0)
    }

}
```

Intentionally this is all done in code for readability but the same can be achieved with constraints.